# Homotopy of a path with different parametrization

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider 2 continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ to a topological space $X$

$$F:[0,1] \to X$$
$$G:[0,1] \to X$$

We have $F([0,1])=G([0,1])$. My question is whether $F$ and $G$ are homotopic. If it's not true in the general case then what property $X$ needs to have for $F$ and $G$ to be homotopic. My intuition is telling me that they should be homotopic since they're the same curve just with different parametrization but I don't have any idea how to prove it

Comment: Do you mean homotopic relative to $\{0, 1\}$? If not, any map $[0, 1] \to X$ is nullhomotopic as $[0, 1]$ is contractible.

Comment: they have the same start and end point, just move between them with different speed

Comment: If $G=F\circ f$ for some continuous $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ then it seems that $H(s,t)=F(sf(t)+(1-s)t)$ does the job. I don't know whether such $f$ necessarily exists.

Comment: If you do in fact mean homotopy relative $\{0,1\}$ then this is false. As you have defined it $F,G$ are not just reparametrisations of the same cure. For instance take $F,G:I\rightarrow S^1$ as paths in the unit circle with $F:t\mapsto exp(2\pi it)$ and $G:t\mapsto exp(-2\pi it)$. Then $F(I)=G(I)=S^1$ but $F\not\simeq G$ rel $\partial I$.

Comment: ah I see, tks a lot

Comment: Is it still true if we remove the loop condition?